# Cannot find svn-python Win32 installer since Tigris->Apache migration

Tags: python, svn

I'm using the svn-python bindings (libsvn) to power Trac on Windows.

Previous to the Tigris->Apache migration of Subversion, I was able to download the Python bindings (`svn-python-*.exe`) here:

http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=11151&expandFolder=11151&folderID=260

What happened to those bindings under the new regime?

Answer (score 0):

I think they're maintained externally, like at http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.6.15/.

Yup:

> The Apache Subversion project does not
>   officially endorse or maintain any
>   binary packages of the Subversion
>   software. However, volunteers have
>   created binary packages for different
>   distributions and platforms, and as a
>   convenience, we maintain a list of
>   links to them here.

The URL above is the only listed as having bindings at http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows.

Comment: I came across those zips at http://alagazam.net/ -- unfortunately, they are not as usable as the installers that used to be hosted on subversion.tigris.org (linked in my original question). Did we really lose those installers during the Tigris->Apache migration?

Answer (score 0):

I needed these today. You can get the 1.6.6 source from Tigris and there is a path "packages\python-windows" which contains a readme and setup.py file. Combine those with the bindings from win32svn 1.6.15 and you can try to generate an installer.

However, it didn't fully work for me. I am getting errors (running mailer.py) saying that there is an error importing module _core (libsvn_core.dll as far as I can see). Not sure why, might be my system, maybe it will work for you.